# Usage of dispatch_once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I understand that `dispatch_once` is something that is equivalent to a `static` variable and that the piece of code inside `dispatch_once` is executed only once throughout the application.

I am going through a huge code base and came across something like this

```
+ (DBHelper *)sharedInstance {

    static DBHelper *sharedDBHelper = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedDBHelper = [[super alloc] initUniqueInstance];
    });

    return sharedDBHelper;
}
```

DBHelper.sharedInstance is used to get an object and is used in a lot of places ot generate objects.

I'm confused as to why dispatch_once is being used here since that would mean you could have only one object of the class?

Comment: the `sharedDBHelper` is assigned only once in runtime – that is a standard pattern of creating _singleton_ instances.

Comment: So what exactly happens when multiple classes use DBHelper.sharedInstance() and get an instance in return? Do they all refer to the same object?

Comment: that means that at first occasion the new instance is created and every further occasion the already existing instance will be used only – this is why it called singleton, because there is only one instance exists in the memory of the actual object during runtime.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard pattern for a *shared instance*, otherwise known as a *faux singleton*.

In many cases programmers choose to use a single object that can be easily accessed from any part of an application - by calling a static method which returns back a reference to the shared object, i.e. `sharedInstance` in your example - as a means to provide communication/shared data between otherwise independent parts of the application.

It is a *faux* singleton pattern as it does not prevent other instances of the same type - `DBHelper` in your example - from being created. A *true singleton* model is one in which only a single instance of the type can ever be created. (Apple used to have sample code showing how to create true singletons, but it was never updated for the post-ARC world, for more details on that including an ARC version see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799696/singleton-in-ios-objective-c-doesnt-prevent-more-than-one-instance/30828622#30828622).)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It's a singleton (a design pattern). You only need one instance of the class instantiated, so that's all you create.

Comment: So what exactly happens when multiple classes use DBHelper.sharedInstance() and get an instance in return? Do they all refer to the same object?

Comment: @rowana - Yes, they all refer to the same instance. And, BTW, the reason they use `dispatch_once` pattern is precisely in case multiple threads call this at the same time. This thread-safe pattern ensures if multiple threads call this at the same time, that the first will instantiate the object and all the rest will retrieve that same, single instance.

Comment: That helps! Thanks Rob!