# Singleton property returns different values depending on invocation

Tags: ios, multithreading, singleton, nsuserdefaults

#### Background

In my app, I have class called FavoritesController that manages objects that the user's marked as favorites, and this favorite status is then used throughout the app. The FavoritesController is designed as a singleton class as there are a number of UI elements throughout the app that needs to know the 'favorite status' for objects in different places, also network requests need to be able to signal that a favorite needs to be invalidated if the server says so.

This invalidation part happens when the server responds with a 404 error, indicating that the favorite object must be removed from the user's favorites. The network fetch function throws an error, which triggers the FavoritesController to remove the object and then send a notification to interested parties that they need to refresh.

#### The problem

When using a unit test to check the quality of the 404 implementation, all methods are triggered as intended – the error is thrown and caught, the FavoritesController deletes the object and sends the notification. In some instances though, the deleted favorite is still there – but it depends on from where the query is done!

If I query inside the singleton the deletion went OK, but if I query from a class that makes use of the singleton, the deletion didn't happen.

#### Design details

- The FavoritesController property `favorites` uses an ivar with all accesses `@synchronized()`, and the value of the ivar is backed by a NSUserDefaults property.
- A favorite object is an NSDictionary with two keys: `id` and `name`.

#### Other info

- One weird thing which I fail to understand why it happens: in some deletion attempts, the `name` value for the favorite object gets set to `""` but the `id` key retains its value.
- <s>I've written unit tests that add an invalid favorite and checks that it gets removed on first server query. This test passes when starting with empty set of favorites, but fails when there is an instance of 'semi-deleted' object as above (that retains its `id` value)</s>
- The unit test now consistently passes, but in live usage the failure to delete remains. I suspect that this is due to NSUserDefaults not saving to disk immediately.

#### Steps I've tried

- Making sure that the singleton implementation is a 'true' singleton, i.e. `sharedController` always returns the same instance.
- I thought there was some sort of 'capture' problem, where a closure would keep its own copy with outdated favorites, but I think not. When NSLogging the object ID it returns the same.

#### Code

FavoritesController main methods

```
- (void) serverCanNotFindFavorite:(NSInteger)siteID {

    NSLog(@"Server can't find favorite");
    NSDictionary * removedFavorite = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self favoriteWithID:siteID]];
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfFavoriteWithID:siteID];
    [self debugLogFavorites];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self removeFromFavorites:siteID completion:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                NSNotification * note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:didRemoveFavoriteNotification object:nil userInfo:@{@"site" : removedFavorite, @"index" : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index]}];
                NSLog(@"Will post notification");
            
                [self debugLogFavorites];
                [self debugLogUserDefaultsFavorites];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];
                NSLog(@"Posted notification with name: %@", didRemoveFavoriteNotification);
            }
        }];
    });

}

- (void) removeFromFavorites:(NSInteger)siteID completion:(completionBlock) completion {
    if ([self isFavorite:siteID]) {
        NSMutableArray * newFavorites = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.favorites];
    
        NSIndexSet * indices = [newFavorites indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary * entryUnderTest, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            NSNumber * value = (NSNumber *)[entryUnderTest objectForKey:@"id"];
            if ([value isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:siteID]]) {
                return YES;
            }
            return NO;
        }];
    
        __block NSDictionary* objectToRemove = [[newFavorites objectAtIndex:indices.firstIndex] copy];
    
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Will remove %@", objectToRemove);
            [newFavorites removeObject:objectToRemove];
            [self setFavorites:[NSArray arrayWithArray:newFavorites]];

            if ([self isFavorite:siteID]) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to remove!");
            
                if (completion) {
                    completion(NO);
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Removed OK");
                
                if (completion) {
                    completion(YES);
                }
            }
        });
    
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Tried removing site %li which is not a favorite", (long)siteID);
        if (completion) {
            completion(NO);
        }
    }
}

- (NSArray *) favorites
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!internalFavorites) {
            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
            dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                self->internalFavorites = [self.defaults objectForKey:k_key_favorites];
            });
            if (!internalFavorites) {
                internalFavorites = [NSArray array];
            }
        }
        
        return internalFavorites;
    }

}

- (void) setFavorites:(NSArray *)someFavorites {

    @synchronized(self) {
        internalFavorites = someFavorites;
    [self.defaults setObject:internalFavorites forKey:k_key_favorites];
    }


}

- (void) addToFavorites:(NSInteger)siteID withName:(NSString *)siteName {
    if (![self isFavorite:siteID]) {
        NSDictionary * newFavorite = @{
                                       @"name"  : siteName,
                                       @"id"    : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:siteID]
                                   };
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSArray * newFavorites = [self.favorites arrayByAddingObject:newFavorite];
            [self setFavorites:newFavorites];

        });
    
        NSLog(@"Added site %@ with id %ld to favorites", siteName, (long)siteID);
    
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Tried adding site as favorite a second time");
    }
}

- (BOOL) isFavorite:(NSInteger)siteID
{
 
    @synchronized(self) {
        
        NSNumber * siteNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:siteID];
        NSArray * favs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.favorites];
        if (favs.count == 0) {
            NSLog(@"No favorites");
            return NO;
        }
        
        NSIndexSet * indices = [favs indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary * entryUnderTest, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            if ([[entryUnderTest objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToNumber:siteNumber]) {
                return YES;
            }
            
            return NO;
        }];
        
        if (indices.count > 0) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    
    return NO;
}
```

Singleton implementation of FavoritesController

```
- (instancetype) init {
    static PKEFavoritesController *initedObject;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        initedObject = [super init];
        self.defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    });
    return initedObject;
}

+ (instancetype) sharedController
{
    return [self new];
}
```

Unit testing code

```
func testObsoleteFavoriteRemoval() {
    
    let addToFavorites = self.expectation(description: "addToFavorites")
    let networkRequest = self.expectation(description: "network request")
    
    unowned let favs = PKEFavoritesController.shared()
    favs.clearFavorites()
    
    XCTAssertFalse(favs.isFavorite(313), "Should not be favorite initially")
    
    if !favs.isFavorite(313) {
        NSLog("Adding 313 to favorites")
        favs.add(toFavorites: 313, withName: "Skatås")
    }
    
    let notification = self.expectation(forNotification: NSNotification.Name("didRemoveFavoriteNotification"), object: nil) { (notification) -> Bool in
        NSLog("Received notification: \(notification.name.rawValue)")

        return true
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        NSLog("Verifying 313 is favorite")
        XCTAssertTrue(favs.isFavorite(313))
        addToFavorites.fulfill()
    }
    
    self.wait(for: [addToFavorites], timeout: 5)
    
    NSLog("Will trigger removal for 313")
    let _ = SkidsparAPI.fetchRecentReports(forSite: 313, session: SkidsparAPI.session()) { (reports) in
        NSLog("Network request completed")
        networkRequest.fulfill()
    }
    

    self.wait(for: [networkRequest, notification], timeout: 10)

    XCTAssertFalse(favs.isFavorite(313), "Favorite should be removed after a 404 error from server")
    
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: It is probably not your issue, but your Singleton creation is not thread safe. See [Objective C Singletons](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) for the accepted method.

Comment: Please show the add favorite method

Comment: @Paulw11 I replaced the singleton implementation as suggested, which highlighted the fact that I get different instances returned by `sharedController`. I then went with the implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30828622/336616, and using an ivar in FavoritesController to avoid problems in UserDefaults providing different values. 

Now I can see that I have the exact same instance providing different values depending on where I query it. 

Comment: You definitely need to be aware of potential multi-threading issues.  All access to your ivar should be `@synchronized` or dispatched serially on a serial dispatch queue.

Comment: You shouldn’t call `@synchronized` with a nil value because [it does nothing](https://github.com/rentzsch/MagicHat/blob/master/objc4-437.1/runtime/objc-sync.m#L293). It’s true that `internalFavorites` becomes non-nil but before then it’s unpredicatable. Recommend using plain `NSObject` stored in an ivar as the token to pass to `@synchronized`, make sure it is created as the initial value so it will be created before any method calls happen. Alternatively `@synchronized(self)` if in doubt.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys That seems to do the trick, I changed to `@synchronized(self)` on the accessors. **But:** there seems to be a delay in when NSUserDefaults writes to disk. The unit test passes now, but when launching the app directly after a successful test, the favorite remains. And what's worse: setting up the app with an invalid favorite and then launching the app to test it in-app, the app doesn't succeed in deleting the invalid favorite. :(

Comment: After you set the defaults you can call `[self.defaults synchronize];` at an appropriate time to make sure all changes are committed, not sure if it will help in your test cases, but it might

Comment: I was almost going to dismiss your latest suggestions based on the fact that I've read [the documentation for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) and interpreted the 'unnecessary and should not be used' as meaning NOOP. I tried it now, and it *does* solve the problem with outdated favorites persisting between unit tests! Happy times! @AllenHumphreys Please write an an answer featuring both the `@synchronized(self)` and `[self.defaults synchronise]` proposals, and I'll grant you the bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give context around my answers, this is what the code in question looked like when suggesting the change:

```
- (NSArray *)favorites {
    @synchronized(internalFavorites) {
        if (!internalFavorites) {
            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
            dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                internalFavorites = [self.defaults objectForKey:k_key_favorites];
            });
            if (!internalFavorites) {
                internalFavorites = [NSArray array];
            }
        }
    }

    return internalFavorites;
}
```

I was suspicious of the check `if (!internalFavorites) {` that followed `@synchronized(internalFavorites)` because that meant that there was an expectation of `@synchronized` being passed `nil`, which [results in a noop](https://github.com/rentzsch/MagicHat/blob/master/objc4-437.1/runtime/objc-sync.m#L284).

This meant multiple calls to to `favorites` or `setFavorites` could happen in funny ways since they wouldn't actually be synchronized. Giving `@sychronized` an actual object to synchronize on was crucial for thread safety. Synchronizing on self is fine, but for a particular class, you have to be careful not to synchronize too many things on self or you'll be bound to create needless blocking. Providing simple `NSObject`s to `@sychronized` is a good way to narrow the scope of what you're protecting.

Here's how you can avoid using `self` as your lock.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    static PKEFavoritesController *initedObject;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        initedObject = [super init];
        self.lock = [NSObject new];
        self.defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    });
    return initedObject;
}

+ (instancetype)sharedController {
    return [self new];
}

- (NSArray *)favorites {
    @synchronized(_lock) {
        if (!internalFavorites) {
            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
            dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                self->internalFavorites = [self.defaults objectForKey:k_key_favorites];
            });
            if (!internalFavorites) {
                internalFavorites = [NSArray array];
            }
        }
    }

    return internalFavorites;
}
```

Regarding the abnormalities between test runs, definitely calling `synchronize` on the `NSUserDefaults` will help because calls to change the defaults are asynchronous, which means other threads are involved. There are like 3 layers of caching as well, and specifically for the purposes of running tests `synchronize` should ensure that things are completely and cleanly committed before Xcode pulls the plug on the test run. The documentation very abruptly insists that it's not a necessary call, but if it truly weren't necessary it wouldn't exist :-). On my first iOS projects, we always called `synchronize` after every defaults change... so, I think that documentation is more aspirational on the Apple engineers' parts. I'm glad this intuition helped you.